# Why is the expected Material button style not applied immediately when my Angular application loads, only later?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

In an Angular app I'm building, I have a toolbar component with three links. The first leads back to the app, the others to different components. Both link elements have `class="mat-button"` applied, because I wanted to use existing styling.

The first component contains a button with attribute `mat-raised-button`.

The second component just contains text.

When the application initially loads, the toolbar looks ugly.

When clicking the second link, the second component is loaded, but the toolbar is still ugly.

When clicking the first link, the first component is loaded and the toolbar looks much better.

If I then click Home, I go back to the app page and the toolbar still looks good.

What I see in the toolbar is that the link elements have very little style applied initially:

[image]

Once I've clicked the first link, they have much more style applied:

[image]

But I thought if I load a module in AppModule, all of the module is loaded, including any available styles.

How can I make it so that the toolbar is pretty also initially? I could just use something other than mat-button, but I'm genuinely curious why this behaviour manifests.

StackBlitz with relevant code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwlrtv

Comment: All I can see is output on given link.... can we see your code?

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: Wondering if this is a stackblitz thing or do you experience this when you run this application on your local PC?

Comment: The same happens when running the app locally as well, so it's not a Stackblitz thing.

I've updated the link to take you to the code editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the toolbar from

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <a routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active" class="mat-button">Home</a>
  <a routerLink="path1" routerLinkActive="active" class="mat-button">Link 1 - Style is applied</a>
  <a routerLink="path2" routerLinkActive="active" class="mat-button">Link 2 - Nothing happens</a>
</mat-toolbar>
```

to

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <a routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active" mat-button>Home</a>
  <a routerLink="path1" routerLinkActive="active" mat-button>Link 1 - Style is applied</a>
  <a routerLink="path2" routerLinkActive="active" mat-button>Link 2 - Nothing happens</a>
</mat-toolbar>
```

and this fixed the problem.

Comment: Very good point! https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview I should be using attributes for button styling, and Material should take care of transforming it into style for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had it with a new Angular 11 installation. Everything is by the book, default values, been close to copy-pasting elements from the material docs so far.
Suddenly I realized the mat-toolbar (`MatToolbarModule`) has no styles and appears like a white space on the page:

[image]

After the first click on any button, the styles would load and stay until the next page reload. I had to go back and check the set up and I found that the `MatCheckboxModule` was not imported. There was no compilation errors/warnings.

**Not imported module would break the styles that belong to other modules**. All modules must be imported.

After importing the Checkbox module the styling went to normal.

[image]